# Python: check is named service is running

Tags: python, network-programming, dns, named

Is there a simple way to check if a named service is running, and running correctly in python?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what system you use but in linux if you want check name service is running will use commnand

```
chkconfig --list  

acpid                     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
alsa-restore              0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
alsa-store                0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
anacron                   0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
apache2                   0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
apparmor                  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on 
apport                    0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
atd                       0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
avahi-daemon              0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
binfmt-support            0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
bluetooth                 0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
bootlogd                  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
brltty                    0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on 
console-setup             0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
cron                      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
cups                      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
dbus                      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
dmesg                     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
```

I think python or bashell can do that.